# unzip the file and parse it to js

Tags: node.js

hi i had tried to unzip the file from my c drive and trying to parse to javascript object
here is the code

```
var AdmZip = require('adm-zip');
var fs = require('fs'), xml2js = require('xml2js');
var parser = new xml2js.Parser();
var paramdata = 'c:/sample/kusuma.zip';
console.log(paramdata);
var zip = new AdmZip(paramdata);
var zipEntries = zip.getEntries();
var obj = [];
var count = 0;
zipEntries.forEach(function(zipEntry) {
    var len = zipEntries.length;
    console.log(zipEntry.toString());
    console.log(zipEntry.entryName);
    fs.readFile("", function(err, data) {
        console.log(data);
        parser.parseString(data, function(err, result) {
            count++;
            console.log(count);
            obj.push(result);

            if (count === len) {
                console.log(obj);
                res.send(obj);
            }

        });
    });

});
```

please check the code once and provide me some more examples

Answer (score 0):

Well, [`fs.readFile()`](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback) is for reading files that are themselves directly on disk, which these aren't.

However, `adm-zip` is already reading in the contents of the `.zip`, so you shouldn't need `fs`. Each `zipEntry` has `getData()` and `getDataAsync()` methods that can be used to retrieve contents.

```
zipEntries.forEach(function (zipEntry) {
    zipEntry.getDataAsync(function (data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
    });
});
```

Also, as `zipEntries` is  an `Array`, you can use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to reduce it to only XML files.

```
var zipEntries = zip.getEntries().filter(function (zipEntry) {
    return !zipEntry.isDirectory && /\.xml$/.test(zipEntry.entryName);
});
```

You'll also want to determine `len` once from the collection rather than from each entry. You can also test that against use `obj.length` rather than having to keep `count` separately:

```
var len = zipEntries.length;
var obj = [];

zipEntries.forEach(function (zipEntry) {
    zipEntry.getDataAsync(function (data) {
        parser.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            obj.push(result);

            if (obj.length === len) {
                res.send(obj);
            }
        });
    });
});
```